# Why doesn't the $state.go transition that is called on logout only transition sometimes on log out?...angular...ui-router

Tags: angularjs, session, angular-ui-router

I have an app that uses sessions to maintain state and authentication. Everything works fine except one thing. The $state.go transition doesn't always fire when the user logs out and the session is destroyed. It transitions back to the login page most of the time but not all of the time. I am using abstract states to resolve whether the user is logged in or logged out and limiting the user to either the dashboard or the login page respectively. Is there a certain order that I have to do things or anything else anybody might see that may be causing this behavior?

My $state config:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider.state('no_session',{
        abstract:true,
        template: "<ui-view/>",
        resolve: {
            authenticated:function($rootScope,$q, Session){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var session = Session.getSession();
                if (session) {
                    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                }
                if (!$rootScope.authenticated){
                    deferred.resolve({authenticated:false});
                } else {
                    deffered.reject({authenticated:true});
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $stateProvider.state('no_session.login', {
    url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/auth/login.html',
        controller:'AuthCtrl'
    });

    $stateProvider.state('session', {
        abstract: true,
        template: "<ui-view/>",
        resolve: {
            authenticated:function($rootScope,$q,Session){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var session = Session.getSession();
                if (session) {
                    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                }
                if ($rootScope.authenticated===true){
                    deferred.resolve({authenticated:true});
                } else {
                    deffered.reject({authenticated:false});
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $stateProvider.state('session.dashboard', {
        url:'/dashboard',
        templateUrl:'app/views/auth/dashboard.html'
    });

});

app.run (function( $rootScope, $state){
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, current, previous, eventObj) {

    });

    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function (event, current, previous, eventObj) {
        if (!$rootScope.authenticated) {
            $state.go('no_session.login');      
        } else {
            $state.go('session.dashboard');
        }
    });
});
```

My Auth controller (Data.get('logout') returns 'success' as well as the login request):

```
app.controller('AuthCtrl', ['$window','$state','$scope','$rootScope', 'Data', function ($window,$state,$scope, $rootScope,  Data) {
    $scope.login = function () {
        var user = $scope.user;
        Data.post('login', {
            user:user
        }).then(function(results){
            if (results.data.status == 'success') {
                Data.toast(results.data);
                $rootScope.authenticated=true;
                $rootScope.name=results.data.name;          
                $rootScope.user_id=results.data.user_id; 
                $window.sessionStorage["session"] = JSON.stringify({authenticated:true});
                $state.go('session.dashboard');
            } else {
                Data.toast(results.data);
                $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);          }
            })
    };

    $scope.logout = function () {
        Data.get('logout').then(function(results){
            $state.go('no_session.login');
            Data.toast(results);
            $rootScope.authenticated=null;
            $rootScope.name=null;
            $rootScope.user_id=null;
            $window.sessionStorage["session"] = null;
        });
    }
}]);
```

My session factory (use to do a lot more but I moved most of the code to the controller):

```
app.factory('Session', ['Data','$rootScope','$q','$window', function(Data, $rootScope,$q,$window){

    var session;

    function init() {
        if ($window.sessionStorage["session"]) {
            session = JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage["session"]);
        }
    }
    init();


    function getSession(){
        return session;
    }

    return {
        getSession: getSession
    }

}]);
```

Actually looking at it now, this factory probably doesn't really do anything anymore and is probably where the problem is. It's only called from the $state resolves and there is probably a way to do that without the factory.I probably should actually move all the $rootScope stuff into the factory to clear it out the $rootScope and if I've learned anything on here returned a promise to the resolves from the factory, but it's such a small application and this session info is the only thing I store there..I don't know. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: TL;DR; in your resolves, shouldn't you `return deferred.promise;` ?

Comment: yup...thanks to your help I came up with the solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I did was return a promise from `Session.getSession()` and used that promise in my resolves. Also as suggested by @Mikko Viitala, I returned a promise from my resolves and accessed the rejected defer in the run block: `$stateChangeError`. I pulled all the session handler stuff out of the login and logout functions of the auth controller and placed them back in the Session factory sending the session data returned from the login request to the factory and storing it in local storage. When the factory is first instantiated it checks for the session data in local storage and sets the session and authenticated variable respectively. The only thing still stored in `$rootScope` is `$rootScope.authenticated`. I use it to show and hide stuff across all views in the application. The best part is the login and logout state changes work like a charm now! Oh and if your wondering what toaster does and don't know about it, check out https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster - its a great module for displaying great looking animated notifications to the user.

The state config:

```
$stateProvider.state('no_session',{
    abstract:true,
    template: "<ui-view/>",
    resolve: {
        authenticated:function($q,Session){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var session = Session.getSession();
            session.then(function(user){
                if (!user.user_id){
                    deferred.resolve();
                } else {
                    deferred.reject({'authenticated':true})
                }
            })
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});

$stateProvider.state('no_session.login', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/auth/login.html',
    controller:'AuthCtrl'
});

$stateProvider.state('session', {
    abstract: true,
    template: "<ui-view/>",
    resolve: {
        authenticated:function($q,Session){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var session = Session.getSession();
            session.then(function(user){
                if (user.user_id){
                    deferred.resolve();
                } else {
                    deferred.reject({'authenticated':false})
                }
            })
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});

$stateProvider.state('session.dashboard', {
    url:'/dashboard',
    templateUrl:'app/views/auth/dashboard.html'
});
```

Then in the run block:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    if (error.authenticated == true){
        $state.go('session.dashboard');
    } else {
        $state.go('no_session.login');
    }
});
```

Then the AuthCtrl:

```
app.controller('AuthCtrl', ['$http','$window','$state','$scope','Session','toaster', function ($http,$window,$state,$scope,Session,toaster) {

$scope.login = function () {
    var user = $scope.user;
    $http.post('api/login',user).then(function(result){
        if (result.data.status == 'error'){
            toaster.pop(result.data.status, "", result.data.message, 4000, 'trustedHtml');
        } else {
            Session.setSession(result.data.user);
            toaster.pop(result.data.status, "", result.data.message, 4000, 'trustedHtml');
            $state.go('session.dashboard');
        }
    });
};

$scope.logout = function () {
    $http.get('api/logout').then(function(result){
        Session.killSession();
        toaster.pop(result.data.status, "", result.data.message, 4000, 'trustedHtml');
        $state.go('no_session.login');
    });
}

}]);
```

And the Session Factory:

```
app.factory('Session', ['$q','$localStorage','$rootScope',function($q,$localStorage,$rootScope){

var session = {};

function init() {
    if ($localStorage.session){
        session = $localStorage.session;
        $rootScope.authenticated = true;
    }
}
init();

function setSession(user){
    session = user;
    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
    $localStorage.session = user;

}

function killSession(){
    session = {};
    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
    delete $localStorage.session;
}

function getSession(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve(session);
    return deferred.promise;
} 

return {
    getSession: getSession,
    setSession: setSession,
    killSession: killSession
}

}]);
```